# Export SVG function in Fireworks only creates outline

Tags: vector, logo, adobe-fireworks, export, svg

There's a pretty big problem I'm having with [Aaron Bealle's Export to SVG script in Fireworks](http://fireworks.abeall.com/extensions/commands/Export/):

So I have a path in Fireworks that I created from a marquee selection (which came from the `magic wand`, some `feathering` and `smooth selection`).

Let's take this image I vectorized in Fireworks from a drawing by someone at the [NHS Designs in Sacramento](http://www.nhsdesigns.com/graphic/tutorials/painting_logo.php) as an example.

[image: Image 1] [(Download Fireworks PNG file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaUoF.png)

When the path is exported as an SVG using the Export script — only the outer edge is taken into account.

So what I get is a black shape on a transparent/white background. (When in fact the black shape was more complicated than that — but was still a single path.)

[image: Image 2] [(Download SVG file)](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/73378294/Test-Fox-Design-logo-black-outline.svg)

How do I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm considering getting a trial of Illustrator and using that instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like compound path is not supported.

But i am able to get it working by

1. Do a "Split Path" - this will turn every element into a separate path object
2. Select the 2 background object and do a "Punch Compound Shape" using the Property Inspector

   - this is to divide the outline from the rest

see result - http://cl.ly/0H3v423K0j3S

Answer (score 0):

This was likely a bug with Aaron Bealle's Export to SVG script, so **I used Illustrator instead** and everything worked as it should.

Here's how to do it:

1. Select path in Adobe Fireworks
2. Go to `Edit > Copy as Vectors`
3. Open Adobe Illustrator, make a new document, and paste

Voila!

Answer (score -1):

Seems like is a compound path? Do you have the fireworks file to take a look?

http://www.twitter.com/chunwui